# Median Selling Price Excel Table

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with different products, listing units and retail value sold like the example below

```
Product  Units  Value
A        10     100
B        15     80
C        30     560
```

I'd like to compare the Average Selling Price with the Median Selling price, so I am looking for a quick formula to accurately calculate the median.

The median function requires the entire series, so for Product A above I would need 10 instances of 10 etc. How can I calculate the Median quickly considering the condensed form of my data?

Answer (score 0):

Without writing your own VBA function to do this there are a couple of approaches that can be taken.

The first expands the data from its compressed frequency count format to generate the full set of observations. This can be done manually or formulaically. On the assumption the latter is required, it can be achieved using a few columns.

[image: Screenshot for first approach]

All the blue cells are formulae.

Column `E`is simply the cumulative of column `B` and `F` is an adjusted version of this. Column `H` is just the values 1 to 55, the total number of observations given by cell `L2`. Column `I` uses the `MATCH()` with its final argument as 1 to match each observation in `H` against the adjusted cumulative in `F`. Column `J` uses the `INDEX()` function to generate the value of the observation. (Observations 1-10 have value 100, 11-25 have value 80 and 26-55 have value 560 in this example). The `MEDIAN()` function is used in cell `M2` with column `J` as its argument.

This approach can be refined to take account of varying numbers of products and data points through the use of the `OFFSET` function to control the range arguments of the `MATCH()`, `INDEX()` and `MEDIAN` functions. And, of course, adjacent cells in columns `I` and `J` could be combined using a single formula - I've shown them separately for ease of explanation.

The second approach involves sorting the data by value (so in this case the data rows would become  Product B in row 2, product A in row 3 and product C left as-is in row 4). It is then a case of identifying the middle observation number (if the number of observations is odd) or the middle pair of observation numbers (if the number of observations is even) and then determining the value(s) corresponding to this/these middle observation(s). In this approach the adjusted cumulative in column `F` is still used but rather than explicitly calculating the values in column `I` and `J` for every observation it can now be restricted to just the middle observation(s).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way around compromises. Either using big amounts of helper cells or  having the table sorted by the values.

1. Helper cells:

[image]

Formula in `F4:AS6`:

```
=IF(COLUMN()<COLUMN($F$4)+$B4,$C4,"end")
```

Formula in `D2`:

```
=MEDIAN(F4:AS6)
```

2. Sorted:

[image]

Formula in `F4` downwards:

```
=SUM($B$3:B3)+1
```

Formula in `D2`:

```
=SUM(LOOKUP(INT(SUM(B4:B6)/2+{0.5,1}),F4:F6,C4:C6))/2
```